# Get elements by two classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementsbyclassname

I am using `getElementsByClassName` to fund multiple elements and change their style but as I found out `getElementsByClassName` is not cross-browser compatible. Can you please help me to simplifie this code. I would prefer a native JS implementation but jQuery will be probably better so it is also fine....

So how can I then loop through the elements an depending on individual class change some style....

```
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("dhSliderMobile"); 

    for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
        if (ele[i].style.display === "block") {
            ele[i].style.display = "none";

            var div = document.getElementsByClassName("dhImageInfoDiv");
            var div1 = document.getElementsByClassName("dhSeriesInfoDiv");
            for (var j = 0; j < div.length; j++) {
                div[j].style.right = 0 + "px";
                div1[j].style.right = 0 + "px";

            }
        }
        else {
            ele[i].style.display = "block";

            var div = document.getElementsByClassName("dhImageInfoDiv");
            var div1 = document.getElementsByClassName("dhSeriesInfoDiv");

            for (var j = 0; j < div.length; j++) {
                div[j].style.right = 40 + "px";
                div1[j].style.right = 40 + "px";
            }
        }
    }



    var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("dhSliderDesktop");    
    for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
        if (ele[i].style.display === "block") {
            ele[i].style.display = "none";

            var div = document.getElementsByClassName("dhImageInfoDiv");
            var div1 = document.getElementsByClassName("dhSeriesInfoDiv");
            for (var j = 0; j < div.length; j++) {
                div[j].style.right = 0 + "px";
                div1[j].style.right = 0 + "px";

            }
        }
        else {
            ele[i].style.display = "block";

            var div = document.getElementsByClassName("dhImageInfoDiv");
            var div1 = document.getElementsByClassName("dhSeriesInfoDiv");

            for (var j = 0; j < div.length; j++) {
                div[j].style.right = 20 + "px";
                div1[j].style.right = 20 + "px";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this, class selector can be used via `.`  read here more :  [Class Selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

```
 var multipleClassresults= $('.yourClass1, .yourClass2');

 var singleClassResults= $('.yourClass1');
```

if you want to loop the results  then do like this

```
$.each(multipleClassresults,function(index, item){
    if($(item).hasClass('yourClassToCheck'))
    {
     //then do some styling 
    }
});
```

Comment: ```singlefoundObj``` may gives multiple elements too.

Answer (score 1):

You can select elements with class names like as under. You can read more about class selector over [here](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

```
elem = $('.classname'); //elements having class `classname`

elem = $('.classname1, .classname2'); //elements  having class `classname1` or  `classname2`
```

Comment: So how can I then loop through the elements an depending on individual class change some style....

Comment: @Jacob Updated the answer. you can check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To do CSS changes with jQuery its like that. You can also use event handlers if they meet the conditions of your counter to do some stuff. Anyways this will point you in the right way (I hope)

```
$('.dhImageInfoDiv, .dhSeriesInfoDiv').css({
  'margin-left':'40px',
  'display':'block' 
})
```

Kind regards,
M

Answer (score 0):

I think, your code will be like that with jQuery

```
$('.dhSliderMobile').toggle(function() {
    if ($(this).is('visible')) { // if is visible
        $('.dhImageInfoDiv, .dhSeriesInfoDiv').css('right', '40px');
        return false; // then set invisible
    }else{
        $('.dhImageInfoDiv, .dhSeriesInfoDiv').css('right', 0);
        return true; // set visible
    }
});
```

[More info about jQuery.toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: I know it hasn't exactly same functionality of yours. I wanted to give an example that may show you main idea.